# Html code rendered on click of url in web view

Tags: android, android-intent, httpclient, android-webview

I want to develop an android application that would open a url in a webView, using shouldInterceptRequest method in webViewClient. I must get the data using HttpClient. So I built the application but as I run the application, the main.xml gets loaded and then when I click on the button html code of the url is seen.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonurl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="visit     www.stackoverflow.com"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/webView1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {


private Button button;

//String strURL="www.facebook.com";


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final Context context=this;
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonurl);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});



}
}
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebView;
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

  String url="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

WebView webView=  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

//MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient=new MyWebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

webView.loadUrl(url);

   // myWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView,url);



}
}
```

MyWebViewClient.java

```
package com.example;

import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;


public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

                public InputStream httpcall(WebView view,String url) {


                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

                BufferedReader reader = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                    result = "";



                    reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    response.getEntity().getContent()
                            )
                    );

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line + "\n";
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( result.getBytes());

                    return byteArrayInputStream;

                //String webData = result.toString();

                 //   return webData;
                //view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.stackoverflow.com", webData, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");


            }



@Override
   public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,String url){

   return new WebResourceResponse("text/json","utf-8",httpcall(view,url));
   }







 }
```

Comment: see this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: @DeepakSwami While developing this app i referred to that link.... but i need to use httclient call... May be this is a basic version but i have to get some more complex codes in this way but i am stuck with the basic implementation. so it would be great if you can tell me where exactly i am doing the mistake... thanks